# how to disabled security warning messages in vb.net

Tags: security, windows-7, vb.net-2010

can someone please tell me how can i disable security warning messages in windows 7 whenever I run an application.

Here is security warning message  that I get every time I run the application that I created in vb.net

Thanks all answers are appreciated

[image: Security Warning message]

Comment: The simplest solution is to copy the application to the C drive (or another local disk).

Comment: The program is running from an untrusted source. You can trust that computer, or you can sign the program to prove its publisher.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Notification once and for all, here's how :

1) Click on your username icom

[image]

2) Select "Change User Account Control Settings"

[image]

3) Set to "Never Notifiy" --> Click OK

[image]

4) DONE!

Please read read the *"Not recommended notification"* before clicking OK

Comment: can i do this programatically? so that when i deploy this application to certain users i do not have to configure their computers individually?